# Shared components across multiple React/Redux apps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

We are currently moving an application from asp.Net to React/Redux and .Net core. The application is really complex so we are  trying to make so that each page its is own module. But there certain components (Modals, PDF viewers, and other specialized viewers) we need to access throughout the application. Is there a way to add these components from other React projects in a specific application without having to load the entire application. Or maybe create a core React/Redux library that goes in the entire application?

Thanks

Note: we are currently using Webpack, ES6, React and Redux

Comment: Are the components you want to share across this application from other React projects that you've built? If so, you should be able to add those specific components to this current application and import them normally. If they are components you reuse often, then gathering them and creating a custom library to use in your projects seems like a great idea.

Comment: we are doing this now, we made npm repo for the components, its separate, and is installed when we need it.

Comment: @adriennetacke how would you import  objects from other applications?

Comment: @user3527318 You can copy the whole component structure and place it in your new app, which you would then import normally. Ex: `import Card from 'components/Card';`. Or you could do what JordanHendrix mentioned above and create a custom npm repo that contains all the components from other projects you need that you would install into your new app.

Answer (score 0):

As a sibling to your `modules` directory, you may have a `shared` directory. Inside here, usually, you'll have directories like `styles/`, `fonts/`, `images/`, and ... `components/`. The components here may be thought of as the atomic structures that create your "molecular" modules. For example, any custom UI components (e.g., buttons, dropdowns, tooltips) go here--assuming you're opting out of MaterialUI.

Then from within your larger "feature" components, you import these components and use them.

As a further step, you can build all your shared components as a private npm module and bring it in that way.

Since Redux is in the discussion, aim to make your routed components be container components. In other words, in `<Route path='/something' component={ThisComponent} />`, `ThisComponent` ought to be a generated container component, via the `connect()()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using a Router as your application could easily break should the .net application change urls.

Another option would be to use something like [React Habitat](https://github.com/DeloitteDigitalAPAC/react-habitat)